# Conditional date formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

The following needs to happen:

Enter a goal date in cell C1 and enter actual completion date in D1 when project complete
D1 will remain blank until project is complete.

If D1 is blank:

STATE 1 -- If C1 is in the future then cell color is white (C1 job not complete and on schedule)

STATE 2 -- If C1 is past then cell color red (C1 job not complete and deadline missed)

If D1 has a date:

STATE 3 -- If D1 is equal to or less than C1 then C1 cell color is green (C1 target date met)

STATE 4 -- If D1 is greater than C1 then C1 cell color is yellow (C1 target not met but job complete)

Thanks!

Comment: Please try phrasing as a question, add in some things you've tried and sprinkle in some politeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example meets your requirements as currently stated:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I am new at excel and had no idea how to do this. Your helpfulness is greatly appreciated!!!